# Multiple entries in a many to many core data model

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have a core data model with ShoppingList and Product entities joined with a many to many relationship. For some reason its not letting me add a Product more than once to a ShoppingList. What do I need to do to have the same product exist multiple times in a ShoppingList?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a many-many relationship, any one Product can appear on many ShoppingLists, and any one ShoppingList can have many Products on it.  But, as you have found, any one product can appear on any one shopping list only once.  (The relationships are represented in the entity definitions as NSSet, which are unordered and cannot have duplicates.)

If you want to record some kind of quantity associated with that product on that shopping list, you need to do things slightly differently.  Rather than have a many-many relationship directly from Product to ShoppingList, create a separate, intermediate entity, call it something like Quantity, and give it an attribute to hold the quantity details.  Then create one-many relationships from Product to Quantity and from ShoppingList to Quantity.